# Multithreading vs multiprocessing with massive cpu

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, multiprocessing, cpu-usage

I have c code that I want running fast as I can on windows

This code in running on range of number, and for each number ,do massive cpu work.

Each nunber is independent on the another numbers.

Because I want it fastest, I want running it on all of my cpu cores.

What I do now is ,for example I need running at range of 0-1000  and I have 10 cores , I create 10 processes of my c code , and seperate the work between them.

Process1 running in range 0-100 , process2 running in range 100-200 and so on.

Os know to seperate each process to diffrent core(because each process use lot of cpu) , so when I look at task manager all of my cores is 100% usage.

In this way each process run like 5 hours (so the allocation time is negligible)

If I will create thread for each core(not process for each core) , I know that os will know to seperate thread to cores, is that will be faster?

Maybe process have diffrent scheduler or something else so thread will running faster.

Maybe lot of process slow down the os vs lot of thread in 1 process

Comment: highly doubt it, your CPUs are already maxed out, what else can they do? The overhead for creating a thread is less than the overhead for creating a process, but in the big scheme of things (your code is executing for hours), the savings in this overhead completely insignificant. Maybe increasing the priority of your processes/threads will help speed things up.

Comment: Maybe process have diffrent scheduler or something else so thread will running faster. When you see 100% ,that no mean you can faster it.   Maybe lot of process slow down the os vs lot of thread in 1 process

Comment: Again, I doubt it. Boiled down, there's not going to be any difference between a thread of execution from a thread and a thread of execution from a process, certainly not from the CPU's perspective anyway. Admittedly, I don't know a thing about Windows scheduler, but it's going to schedule processes and threads based on availability and priority. But code it up and find out, it shouldn't be a huge effort to convert multi-process to multi-threaded. If you really want speedup, you'll need faster hardware or more efficient algorithms. Maybe you could use a GPU?

Answer (score 0):

> If I will create thread for each core(not process for each core) , I
>   know that os will know to seperate thread to cores, is that will be
>   faster?

The OS knows how to allocate threads to cores in an efficient manner -- however, the OS also knows how to allocate processes to cores in an efficient manner, so it's unlikely that you would see any difference in performance simply by switching from a multi-process module to a multi-threaded model.  That is, you're already getting the benefit you're hoping to obtain.

For a problem like this, you'd probably be better off looking for ways to optimize your processing loops (e.g. maybe you can use SSE instructions, or find a more efficient algorithm?)

Comment: How can I use SSE instructions in c code on windows? Is that really  speed up code?  By the way windows will not be slower when I allocate 10 processes vs allocate 10 threads?

Comment: I can't think of any reason *why* Windows would be slower with 10 processes than it would be with 10 threads, at least not when running on a 10-core machine.  The same code is running either way.  As for SSE instructions, that is a whole different topic, you'll have to google it.

Answer (score -1):

> simple explanation: https://www.techopedia.com/definition/24297/multithreading-computer-architecture
>
> Multithreading is a type of execution model that allows multiple threads to exist within the context of a process such that they execute independently but share their process resources. A thread maintains a list of information relevant to its execution including the priority schedule, exception handlers, a set of CPU registers, and stack state in the address space of its hosting process.
>
> Threading can be useful in a single-processor system by allowing the main execution thread to be responsive to user input, while the additional worker thread can execute long-running tasks that do not need user intervention in the background. Threading in a multiprocessor system results in true concurrent execution of threads across multiple processors and is therefore faster. However, it requires more careful programming to avoid non-intuitive behavior such as racing conditions, deadlocks, etc.
>
> Operating systems use threading in two ways:
>
> **Pre-emptive multithreading** in which the context switch is controlled by the operating system. Context switching might be performed at an inappropriate time, Hence, a high priority thread could be indirectly pre-empted by a low priority thread.
>
> **Cooperative multithreading** in which context switching is controlled by the thread. This could lead to problems, such as deadlocks, if a thread is blocked waiting for a resource to become free.
>
> **The 32- and 64-bit versions of Windows use pre-emptive multithreading** in which the available processor time is shared such that all the threads get an equal time slice and are serviced in a queue-based mode. During thread switching, the context of a pre-empted thread is stored and reloaded in the next thread in the queue. The time slice is so short that the running threads seem to be executing in parallel.

Your question I think quickly gets into the realm of parallel programming, and to a lesser extent how a given Operating System behaves and handles processes, or threads.

To take a stab at an answer, to run as fast as possible

- you would NOT want to kick off multiple instances of an executable, certainly not in Windows
- I don't know about in Windows, but in Linux there what is known as **CPU affinity** which will lock a given thread to a specific core for the life of the thread, otherwise the linux operating system  can bounce it around to different cores... as linux thinks it's managing everything going on as efficient as possible; this is not the case when the goal is to run only your code as fast as possible since there is overhead moving threads to different CPU cores
- you would want to reprogram your C code using either **OpenMP**, or **PTH** known as pthreads.  Openmp is a higher level language using directives in C and handled by the C compiler and makes parallel programming relatively easy.  PTH is more fine grained programming and can be harder to learn and write code for, but using PTH *may* allow you to write code that would run the fastest.  Whether parallel programming in PTH is faster than OpenMP is debated and in my opinion very dependent on the algorithm you are trying to implement.
- and depending on your algorithm, the fastest way may be with GPU cores using CUDA provided you have an NVidia graphics card.  *I believe ATI/AMD cards can also do something similar now but i don't know their terminology.*
- also multi process is basically for applications or the execution of completely separate programs at the same time; multi thread is smaller multi tasks of the same program or process and has less overhead and would be faster for what you want; look up difference between multiprocess and multithread.  Inter-process communication is resource intensive, and should be avoided in your case, don't create multiple processes.

Comment: *I have c code that I want running fast as I can on windows.*  That's problem 1, use linux.  sorry, couldn't resist

Comment: *"use linux"* - Which distribution? Which version? What configuration? Why does this improve a compute-bound operating? Be specific, please.

Comment: "compute-bound" is still completely controlled by the operating system (windows or linux or other)  Much overhead & inefficiency can happen at the level of multi thread (or multi process) execution, my description of CPU affinity for one.  As an example Linux you *can* modify the kernel and rebuild , go to run level 3 vs run level 5, disable various services and strip unneeded things out of the kernel to have the kernel focus more on just your code... to run it as fast as possible as was initially asked.

Comment: Let me know how you might to do anything like that with Windows, this is also stackoverflow **Unix & Linux**, not Windows.  And

Comment: *90 percent of the world's top 500 fastest supercomputers, while Windows runs 1 percent of them*.  www.zdnet.com/article/fast-faster-fastest-linux-rules-supercomputing/

Comment: Anonymous MSFT developer admits Linux is faster than Windows  https://www.zdnet.com/article/anonymous-msft-developer-admits-linux-is-faster-than-windows/

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't make much sense out of those comments. It seems like most sentences are cut off or presented out of context. It's still unclear, how *"using Linux"* would magically increase the throughput of a compute-bound operation. Changing the Linux kernel and recompiling it is hardly feasible in the vast majority of cases, and the potential performance improvements are probably not even worth mentioning when confronted with the problem outlined in this question. Reasons for using Linux to drive custom hardware are more likely the ability to actually make it run on that hardware.